# Direct proof that $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n}{n!}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, binomial-theorem

Is there a direct proof that $$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n}{n!}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^n?$$

We dont know what logarithms or exponentials are.

Comment: There is. It is unpleasant to type, though the idea is not very hard. Expand $(1+x/n)^n$ using the Binomial Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Applying the Binomial theorem,
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^n = \lim_{n\to\infty}1+x+\frac{(n-1)x^2}{2n}+\frac{(n-2)(n-1)x^3}{6n^2}+\frac{(n-3)(n-2)(n-1)x^4}{24n^3}+\frac{(n-4)(n-3)(n-2)(n-1)x^5}{120n^4}+... \\
=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+\frac{x^5}{120}+... \\
=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n}{n!}.
\end{equation*}
Note that we used L'Hopital's rule when taking the limits because we had the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

Comment: If you sum up infinitely many sequences, it is not always the case that the limit of the sum equals the sum of the limits. A justification of the interchange would be nice.

Comment: You have to do two things: (1) show that $(1+x/n)^n \le \sum x^n/n!$, which is easy, and (2) $\lim (1+x/n)^n \ge \sum x^n/n!$, which is not. It's the usual idea of splitting a sum into two parts, a nice part and a not-nice part.

Comment: @marty cohon That did occur to me, just in the same way that proving two topological quantities are equal to each other is done by showing they are subsets of each other.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer I accidentally overlooked that. In general, would uniform convergence be enough for this to be okay?

Comment: Depends on what is uniform in what metric. We have a sum $$s_k = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n^{(k)},$$ and have $a_n^{(k)} \xrightarrow{k\to\infty} a_n$. We want $$\lim_{k\to\infty} s_k = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n.$$ Obviously it's not enough that $\sup \{ \lvert a_n^{(k)} - a_n\rvert : n \in \mathbb{N}\} \to 0$. Here, you could argue with monotone convergence (for $x \geqslant 0$; for $x < 0$, you could split into odd and even part and use monotone convergence on each part separately, or dominated convergence).